# Getting around the "Please be careful" interstitial page

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-canvas, interstitial

When we create a new FB Ad that directs to an FB page that in turn is set to redirect to the external website the FB page administers, FB displays an interstitial web page before redirecting that shows a "Please be careful" warning message.  You can see this interstitial web page here:

http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=htt...

This interstitial is guaranteed to lose some of the traffic we are paying for.

We're wondering whether we can direct to an FB App or canvas page instead that includes the same content (video along with a FB comment stream) without getting the interstitial "Please be careful" FB web page?

Does anyone have experience with this "Please be careful" interstitial web page and know when it will be triggered?